# Save as image canvas mixed with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, canvas

I know that it is possible to save the content's of a `canvas` as an image, on the client side, using only `javaScript`.

I have a photo and I want to add some text over it, style the text with CSS, and then save the resulting image, all this on the client side.

Is that possible?

There would be awesome if there was some `javaScript` library to transform all HTML elements styled by CSS in canvas shapes.

Comment: I would suggest editing the text through canvas also. If you're brave - do everything through SVG. Easier to create and edit, but harder to save as a rasterized image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [HTML-2-canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) project. It'll convert your entire web page (or a particular tag that you want) to a canvas object.

So in your case you will have HTML + canvas converted into Canvas. Then you can save it as a picture.

Comment: This is a whole rendering engine in Javascript! Pretty impressive.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Javascript Canvas FileReader <- needs alot of support to work

so only in the latest browsers.

in this example you upload an image which will be resized mantaining the aspect ratio and it will add some text at the top left.And this all client side

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
var
maxSize=600, // Max width or height of the image
font='"italic small-caps bold 40px/50px arial";', // font style
fontColor='white', // font color
text='HELLO', // TEXT
textX=50, // text x position
textY=50, // text y position
h=function(e){
 var fr=new FileReader();
 fr.onload=function(e){
  var img=new Image();
  img.onload=function(){
   var r=maxSize/Math.max(this.width,this.height),
   w=Math.round(this.width*r),
   h=Math.round(this.height*r),
   c=document.createElement("canvas"),cc=c.getContext("2d");
   c.width=w;c.height=h;
   cc.drawImage(this,0,0,w,h);

   cc.font=font;
   cc.fillStyle=fontColor;
   cc.fillText(text,textX,textY);

   this.src=c.toDataURL();
   document.body.appendChild(this);
  }
  img.src=e.target.result;
 }
 fr.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById('f').addEventListener('change',h,false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="f">
</body>
</html>
```

and here is a nice tutorial to add text effects

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/texteffects/

Answer (score 1):

**Without knowing more about your project, you might look at using native Canvas – without CSS**

Canvas alone does a fair job of letting you put text on an image

- font-face
- font-size
- color
- text-shadow
- opacity
- gradient text
- and more...

With not that much extra effort, you can do more (still within canvas itself):

- text align (using context.measureText)
- outline text (stroke without fill using strokeText)
- Cut-out text revealing the image underneath (globalCompositeOperation)
- Text on a path (using transforms)